# Ansible Register Multiple Async Tasks to the Same Variable

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to register multiple async tasks to the same variable? For example if I have two tasks that each invoke an async shell command:

```
  - name: Run async task 1
    shell: echo "task 1"
    async: 30
    poll: 0
    register: db_wait

  - name: Run async task 2
    shell: echo "task 2"
    async: 30
    poll: 0
    register: db_wait

  - debug: msg="task vars {{db_wait}}"
```

When I print the db_wait variable it only contains the reference of one task.

```
 "msg": "task vars {u'started': 1, u'results_file': u'/home/vagrant/.ansible_async/202582702042.7326', u'ansible_job_id': u'202582702042.7326', u'changed': False}"
```

Is there a way to register the same variable for the async tasks or some sort of list I can add to and can iterate at a later point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with the following solution in the end, hopefully it may help other people. The core of the problem is I needed to run some long running tasks on different hosts in different plays, but only want to gather the results at the very end of the playbook.

For the plays to run the jobs I have:

```
---
- name: Long Running tasks 1
  hosts: remote_host_1
  tasks:
    - name: Tasks 1
      shell: "{{item}}"
      with_items:
        - sleep 10
        - echo "Another Task"
      async: 3600
      poll: 0
      register: wait_task1


- name: Long Running tasks 2
  hosts: remote_host_2
  tasks:
    - name: Tasks 2
      shell: "{{item}}"
      with_items:
        - sleep 20
      async: 3600
      poll: 0
      register: wait_task2
```

Then the final plays were to check the results:

```
- name: Verify Async Tasks 1
  hosts: remote_host_1
  tasks:
    - include: "/ansible/plays/check_results.yml wait={{wait_task1}}"


- name: Verify Async Tasks 2
  hosts: remote_host_2
  tasks:
    - include: "/ansible/plays/check_results.yml wait={{wait_task2}}"
```

And the check results looks familiar to people who have used this mechanism:

```
---
- name: Check Results
  async_status: jid={{ item.ansible_job_id }}
  register: task_result
  until: task_result.finished
  retries: 120
  delay: 30
  failed_when: task_result.rc != 0
  with_items: wait.results
```

This kicks off all tasks asynchronously and then we can gather the results at the end for each play.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way you would be able to do what you want is if you rewrote your example along these lines:

```
- name: run tasks 
  shell: {{ item }}
  async: 30
  poll: 0
  register: db_wait
  with_items:
    -  echo "task 1"
    -  echo "task 2"
```

Since this is a single task that iterates over a loop of items then all the results will end up in the same register variable.  In the example you provided, the variable will always be overwritten by the second task since tasks are distinct.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, however I already do this on my tasks and this was the only way I knew how to run multiple commands and get the callbacks. However in my real code I have multiple plays which have their own async tasks and was wondering if I could just use a single variable to store all the results and check at the end of the playbook.

Answer (score 1):

Seven years later and I'm here to offer an alternative solution :) I stumbled across this thread while researching how to deal with this issue. This is how I dealt with in in 2022.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    # Create an empty array to store job ids
    - set_fact:
        job_ids: []

    # Do a thing .....
    - name: Sleep for thirty seconds
      command: sleep 30
      async: 1000
      poll: 0
      register: _action

    # Add the job ID to action_array
    - set_fact:
        job_ids: "{{ job_ids + [_action.ansible_job_id] }}"

    # Do something else ...
    - name: Sleep for one minute
      command: sleep 60
      async: 1000
      poll: 0
      register: _action
    
    # Also add this job ID to job_ids array
    - set_fact:
        action_array: "{{ job_ids + [_action.ansible_job_id] }}"

    # Let's take a look at what we have
    - debug:
        var: job_ids

    # Wait until all jobs have complete
    - name: wait all tasks to finish
      async_status:
        jid: "{{ a_job_id }}"
      register: job_result
      until: job_result.finished
      retries: 80
      delay: 15
      loop: "{{ job_ids }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: a_job_id
        label: "Job {{ a_job_id }} has completed"
```

Here's my terminal output from the playbook above

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Sleep for thirty seconds] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Sleep for one minute] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "action_array": [
        "181666307608.2006658",
        "227123662413.2006687"
    ]
}
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (80 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (79 retries left).

TASK [wait all tasks to finish] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=Job 181666307608.2006658 has completed)
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (80 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (79 retries left).
changed: [localhost] => (item=Job 227123662413.2006687 has completed)

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=7    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
pipenv run ansible-playbook temp.yml  7.21s user 0.64s system 12% cpu 1:03.97 total    PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Sleep for thirty seconds] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Sleep for one minute] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "action_array": [
        "181666307608.2006658",
        "227123662413.2006687"
    ]
}
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (80 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (79 retries left).

TASK [wait all tasks to finish] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=Job 181666307608.2006658 has completed)
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (80 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (79 retries left).
changed: [localhost] => (item=Job 227123662413.2006687 has completed)

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=7    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
pipenv run ansible-playbook temp.yml  7.21s user 0.64s system 12% cpu 1:03.97 total
```

Hope this helps someone!