# If-Else conditions with the same registered value in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to build a playbook that will perform Action A if When statement is True and Action B if statement is false.
Sounds easy, point is that both actions are the same with a change:

```
    - name:                       Listing AMI Express
    ec2_ami_facts:
      filters:
        "name":                 Dev-AMI
    with_items:                 "{{ sites }}"
    when:                       site not in sites
    register:                   ami

  - name:                       Listing AMI Standard
    ec2_ami_facts:
      filters:
        "name":                 Prod-AMI
    with_items:                 "{{ sites }}"
    when:                       site in sites
    register:                   ami
```

As I understand, the result here will always be the one from the last action, if the first action is True and the last action is False, the "ami" is from the last output - simply empty. If the last action is True, the result will display the correct "ami".

If I separate it to different names, aka, ami1 and ami2 - it will work properly, but my later tasks requires the variable of "ami".

So what is the correct and proper way to achieve this?
Use the same var depends on the conditional when.

Thanks in advance and sorry if my topic wasn't clear enough :)

Comment: Variable set in `register` is never empty. If the task is skipped, it contains this very information (skipped) and overwrites previous value ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32737364/2947502) shows a trick to "select" the correct value, in your case the included file would have to check if the task was skipped).　However, you don't need two tasks and such tricks to achieve what you want, just put a Jinja2 template in the `filters` declaration and use a condition inside that template to produce either `Dev-AMI` or `Prod-AMI`.

Comment: Thanks.
I'm not sure exactly how I can use it.
Is that correct?

      - name:                       Listing AMI Express
        ec2_ami_facts:
          region:                   "{{ region }}"
          filters:
            "{{ ( "name" == 'Dev-AMI' ) | ternary ('Dev-AMI','Prod-AMI') }}"
        with_items:                 "{{ sites }}"
        when:                       site not in sites
        register:                   ami

Comment: No. Please read the answer under the dup-target and try with a `debug` module first, to get an understanding how things work.　You also need to define whole dictionary for the `filters`, that is including `"name":`.